# Problem with list all dfs files, i want to select only one

Tags: powershell, file, storage

I need your help only limiting to a single path and not showing all paths from the dfs

```
Get-FsrmQuota | Format-Table Path, @{Name='Tamaño';Expression={$_.Size / 1MB}}, @{Label=”Usage GB”; Expression={$($_.usage/1MB) -as [int] }}, @{Label=”Fecha”; Expression={(Get-Date)}} -auto
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x91Bz.png)

Comment: But i want to select the path :c

Comment: Sorry it was a sad emoji face :(  Can you help me define the path in the syntax?

Comment: Olaf i have a problem , please check the last image

Comment: Olaf you are my hero, I am super grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-FsrmQuota | 
    Where-Object { $_.Path -like 'C:/RUTA*' } |
        Select-Object -First 1 |
            Format-Table Path, @{Name = 'Tamaño'; Expression = { $_.Size / 1MB } }, @{Name = 'Usage GB'; Expression = { $($_.usage / 1MB) -as [int] } }, @{Name = 'Fecha'; Expression = { (Get-Date) } } -AutoSize
```

Comment: Get-FsrmQuota | Where-Object  {$_.Path -like 'C:/RUTA'} but i only need in a table size and usage in GB

Comment: Could you help me by mp, if I could send you the images it would be fantastic

Comment: I'll try and tell you sorry but I don't speak English well

Comment: OK, changed my code again with the new requirement you told in your last "answer"  ;-)

Comment: you are my hero, I am super grateful